# database records show without refreshing the page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm trying to show the database values using ajax function. When I add a new row into my database table it doesn't show the records immediately. I have to refresh my page. Then only it shows the recent log details. I think I have a problem with ajax coding. I'm newbie to ajax. Someone help me to solve my issue..

```
function updateDriver(event)
{
    $(".panel a").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("active"))
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        });


    $(this).addClass("active");
    ajaxObj.options.previousDriver = ajaxObj.options.data['did'];   
    ajaxObj.options.data = {'aid':'<?=$agent_id?>','did': event.data.did};

    //Ajax call for Driver Log Update;

    //function refreshEachMinute() {
      $("#RecentLog").html('Loading...');

      $.ajax({
              url: "<?=LOAD_LOG?>/",//The resource that delivers loc data.
              method: 'post', //data method
              dataType:'html',
              data: { aid: "<?=$agent_id?>", did: event.data.did },
              success: function(data)
              {
                  $('#RecentLog').html(data);
              },
              error: function()
              {
                  $('#RecentLog').html('<p>No Entries</p>')
              }

      });
    //}
    //setInterval(refreshEachMinute, 200);

}
```

PHP

```
case LOAD_LOG:

    if(!isset($_POST['aid']))
    die();

            $agent_id = $_POST['aid'];
            $driver_id = $_POST['did'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_DRIVER_LOG." where driver_id='$driver_id' ORDER BY id DESC";
            $log_data = asort_result_array($sql);
            $driver_log ="";
            if(count($log_data))
            foreach($log_data as $log)
            {
                extract($log);

                $ago = TimeAgo($date_of_update);                
                echo '<p>
                <span>'.$ago.', @ '.$average_speed.'km/hr</span><br>
                <span style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;">'.$current_place.'</span>
                </p>
                <hr class="tabhr">';

            }
            else
            echo "No Entries";



        exit();
```

Comment: How you are calling this ajax? I mean is there any click event which requests for this ajax?

Comment: @jai: I have updated my ajax codes..

Answer (score 1):

The database can't trigger your javascript function. you have to do that from client side every few intervals. you can use `window.setInterval` for that.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   //your ajax function.
}, 200);//every 200 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do this from the same page?  Try separating your PHP into a different file.  When you are appending the LOAD_LOG query string and then refreshing the page, you said it only shows those entries, so that suggests to me that your case statement is basically writing the whole page.

You might have more success if you create a separate PHP file, say 'loadlog.php', then you can replace the url option in your ajax with your/path/to/loading.php.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, looked at it too quickly and thought you were appending as a query string to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what besabestin said ...

u can use setTimeout instead of setInterval  if you want it to execute just one time

```
  window.setInterval(function(){
   //your ajax function.
}, 200);
```